# stuck at Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart, gradle

i'm runing Pop_OS! 20.10

```
flutter doctor -v
```

> [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.3, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8) •
> Flutter version 1.22.3 at /home/samdc/DevTools/flutter • Framework
> revision 8874f21 (3 months ago), 2020-10-29 14:14:35 -0700 • Engine
> revision a1440ca392 • Dart version 2.10.3 • Pub download mirror
> https://pub.flutter-io.cn • Flutter download mirror
> https://storage.flutter-io.cn
>
> [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
> version 30.0.3) • Android SDK at /home/samdc/DevTools/Android/SDK •
> Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3 • Java binary at:
> /opt/android-studio/jre/bin/java • Java version OpenJDK Runtime
> Environment (build
> 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593) • All Android licenses accepted.
>
> [!] Android Studio • Android Studio at /opt/android-studio ✗ Flutter
> plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality. ✗ Dart
> plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality. •
> android-studio-dir = /opt/android-studio • Java version OpenJDK
> Runtime Environment (build
> 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
>
> [✓] VS Code (version 1.52.1) • VS Code at /usr/share/code • Flutter
> extension version 3.18.1
>
> [✓] Connected device (1 available) • Google Nexus 5 (mobile) •
> 192.168.56.101:5555 • android-x86 • Android 5.1 (API 22)

```
dart --version
```

> Dart SDK version: 2.10.3 (stable) (Tue Oct 27 14:44:30 2020 +0100) on
> "linux_x64"

```
java --version
```

> openjdk 14.0.2 2020-07-14 OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
> 14.0.2+12-Ubuntu-1) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.2+12-Ubuntu-1, mixed mode, sharing)

```
gradle -v
```

> ```
> Gradle 6.8
>
> Build time: 2021-01-08 16:38:46 UTC
> Revision: b7e82460c5373e194fb478a998c4fcfe7da53a7e
>
> Kotlin: 1.4.20
> Groovy: 2.5.12
> Ant: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.9 compiled on September 27 2020
> JVM: 14.0.2 (Private Build 14.0.2+12-Ubuntu-1)
> OS: Linux 5.8.0-7630-generic amd64
> ```

When i try to run flutter app from terminal using `flutter run` i get this massege

> ```
> Launching lib/main.dart on Google Nexus 5 in debug mode...
> Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
> ```

and it will be stuck forever .

and as the emulator i'm using genymotion
and i'm using VPN because my country is banned from using google services , and the internet speed is unstable .
and also i tried to run the app from VS Code with no luck .
i've been trying to install flutter for 2 weeks with no luck , hope find the solution

things i tried :
flutter clean
I have changed the Gradle wrapper properties distribution URL version to: 6.8-all

Edit : afyer a while of waiting the `flutter run` command throw this error

> Launching lib/main.dart on Google Nexus 5 in debug mode... Running
> Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
> Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: error in
> opening zip file Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
> at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)             Running
> Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
> at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:225)        Running
> Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
> at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:155)        Running
> Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
> at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:169)        Running
> Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
> at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:214)    Running
> Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
> at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27) Running
> Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
> at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:74)    Running
> Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
> at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)    Running
> Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
> at
> org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
> Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
> at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48) Running
> Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
> at
> org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
> Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
> at
> org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
> Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
> Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done
> 470.0s (!) [!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download... Exception in thread "main"
> java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
> at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
> at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:225)
> at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:155)
> at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:169)
> at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:214)
> at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)
> at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:74)
> at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
> at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
> at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
> at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
> at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
> Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
> Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done
> 0.2s [!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download... Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug
> failed with exit code 1

Comment: Is terminal showing any type of error  or it's just assemble Debug.

Comment: No , it is not showing any type of error .

Comment: Normally for first time it can take 15-20 minutes nearly to process , just  leave it running as much as time it is taking because if there would be any problem  it show's error , assemble debug is process in which you app builds so, till it is not completed you cannot say surely there is error or not so let it complete, if it shows error after assemble debug  let me know

Comment: @AmitKumar  after a while it show an error .

Comment: Can you tell me the details of error

Comment: my bad, i edited the post and add the error

Comment: Looks very similar to this other question, take a look:
[exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67901965/flutter-gradle-task-assembledebug-failed-with-exit-code-1-zip-end-header-not-fou)

Answer (score 0):

I have dealt with this exact issue in the past, what worked for me was I uninstalled flutter sdk, android studio and all the elements I installed related to flutter and repeated the process of installing flutter and all of the components it requires. If this does not work, I suggest not using the emulator but using a physical device to run your code.

Comment: well ..  that will be my last shot.