# Flutter Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1 zip END header not found

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

Hello I am new to Flutter I have setup flutter with android studio 4.2.1, and every thing is fine. When I try to run it; it show me following error
I see too much questions but it is not helpfull for me
flutter doctor run no issue found
[Hers is doctor result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwxPp.png)

Here is my [enviroment variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuWhv.png)

can any one guide me how can I run the flutter. I am lunching it in a chrome

> exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found   at
> java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.zerror(ZipFile.java:1567)  at
> java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.findEND(ZipFile.java:1462)     at
> java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.initCEN(ZipFile.java:1469)     at
> java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.(ZipFile.java:1274)  at
> java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1237)     at
> java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.(ZipFile.java:727)
> at
> java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.get(ZipFile.java:844)
> at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:247)     at
> java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:177)  at
> java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:191)  at
> org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:214)    at
> org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)    at
> org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:74)    at
> org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)    at
> org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
> at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)   at
> org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
> at
> org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
> Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I recently Solved this problem.
This Problem came from *gradle* file is corrupted in my system.
I'm using Linux so this steps almost same in windows also. This answer is for any gradle version.

Open File Manager:
enable *Show hidden folder* from top menu bar.

You may find this location : *.gradle>wrapper>dists*.

In Linux: *Home > .gradle > wrapper > dists*.

In Windows: *C:>Users>{PC Name}>.gradle>wrapper>dists*

---

### Method 1

1. Go inside **gradle-6.5-all > dists > 2oz4ud9k3tuxjg84bbf55q0tn**. `'2oz4ud9k3tuxjg84bbf55q0tn'` may be different in your PC.
2. Delete all files in that folder and download required file manually: https://downloads.gradle-dn.com/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip
   [image]
3. after download paste freshly downloaded zip file in that folder.
4. Run your project `flutter run -v`

---

### Method 2

Try this if you have fast & stable internet connection.

1. Delete that **gradle-6.5-all** folder.
   [image]
2. Open project in VS code or Android Studio and open terminal.
3. Run this command *flutter run -v*

---

### Method 3

Flutter Doctor will give right result.

1. Open Android Studio
2. Create new flutter project
3. Click on `Tools > flutter >Flutter for editing` in android studio

and wait, flutter doctor takes time to identify problem.

---

Use this link for download gradle file.
Replace `6.5` with your gradle version.
https://downloads.gradle-dn.com/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip

I hope this answer helpful for you.

Comment: For me I don't have the `gradle-6.7.1-bin`. What can I do? I'm using MacOS.

Comment: You can easily let the system download your gradle version automatically when you´re connected to the internet and doing a ´flutter run´, just make sure to have all of your processes related to the build allowed in the firewall, and it´s done.

Answer (score 24):

Please use the below command

**1.Mac User :**

```
rm -rf ~/.gradle
```

**2.Windows User :**

remove the .gradle file

```
.gradle file location -> C:\Users\myUser
```

Answer (score 8):

***I faced the same problem in VSCode when I wanted to run the Flutter app I got that error, so after lots of debugging and research, I found the solution. it's pretty easy, just follow these steps:***

### In windows 10:

**1. Open flutter project in a Text-Editor like VSCode.**

**2. Open android -> gradle -> wrapper -> gradle-wrapper.properties**
[image: find gradle wrapper properties]

**3. You will find "gradle-6.7.1.all.zip" inside gradle-wrapper folder**

**4. Go to this path: C:\Users\your-user**
[image: find .gradle folder in windows]

**5. Then go to the wrapper->dists and find "gradle-6.7.1.all" folder**
[image: find gradle file in android]

**5. Delete this folder.**

**6. Then come to VSCode and open Terminal.**

**7. Please make sure that you have stable internet connection then type this command in terminal**

**8. flutter run**

*I hope this solution can help you!*

Comment: For me, this was also my issue. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: if you change the gradle  version in wrapper properties then its also works

Answer (score 6):

I solve this error by updating the gradle plugin/version. I have as part of my configuration:

- Windows 10
- Android Studio 4.2.1
- Java 11: Android Studio 4.2.1 don't have support for JDK 16, so, I installed JDK 11, and configured the AS ([how to change the jdk in AS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30631286/how-to-specify-the-jdk-version-in-android-studio)) to use this older JDK
- Gradle 7.0.1

By default, when you create a new Flutter project, the IDE created it with basic standard configurations, so you have to change this configs to fit your current config. For that, you need to update the gradle config in the flutter project, as follow:

- in `android/gradle/build.gradle` file: update the gradle plugin to 4.2.0 in the dependencies section, like this:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0'
    //more dependencies
}
```

- in  `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file: update the gradle version, in this case I have the 7.0.1, feel free to use another one, like this

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.1-all.zip
//more attributes
```

After you change the gradle config, run this commands in your project:

- `flutter clean` : clean the project
- `flutter pub get` : update your dependencies
- `flutter run` : run the project. Now it must work, at least it work for me

Comment: i have solved my problem wi t this one "distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.1-all.zip" thank

Comment: distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip

Answer (score 2):

This error is caused by corrupted **gradle** files, this is either due to incomplete downloads due to network issues. To solve it easily download the gradle zipped file from https://downloads.gradle-dn.com/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip and paste on the .gradle directory as shown below if you are on linux
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jefqv.png)

Answer (score 2):

I solve this error by deleting the .gradle folder.

This location is gradle folder
In Windows: C:> Users> {PC Name}>. Gradle

After deleting this folder, you only need to run the application again in Android Studio. At this point, Android Studio starts downloading the deleted folder automatically.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75kFk.png)

Answer (score 1):

I try all method but it did not work for me so i decided to location the gradle-wrapper.properties in the andriod folder then i change the distribution  gradle link to a more recent gradle link.

Comment: Is your post an answer for the question above?  If yes then, at least, explain that the described procedure has worked for you.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32001132)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome SO.

Java 16/latest version is not fully compatible with the Gradle 6 at this moment. Try to use java 11 or 8, it will resolve your issue.

Comment: added but still same issue

Comment: i think flutter  file is missing dart.exe because in documentation  when you run this command (where flutter dart)  these are output (C:\dev\src\flutter\bin\flutter
  C:\dev\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat
  C:\dev\src\flutter\bin\dart
  C:\dev\src\flutter\bin\dart.bat
  C:\dev\src\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe) when i run this command  output is C:\Windows\system32>where flutter dart
C:\flutter\bin\flutter
C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat
C:\flutter\bin\dart
C:\flutter\bin\dart.bat

Comment: flutter doctor giving you the correct result. did you try `Tools->flutter->open for editing in android studio` option?

Comment: No but now  i install vs studio but same error in it i dont get whats the reason is :(

Comment: i Stuck here 2 days and i install setup 5,6 time :(

Comment: open your android module only in android studio (not the complete flutter project). try to run then. make sure the project is newly created. looks like installation is not correctly done

Comment: android is working when i run android android project it works fine android studio working properly

Comment: Confirm that you have added the jdk and jre in environment path. and `java -version` resulting 11 or 8 version (not 16)

Answer (score 0):

I changed gradle-wrapper.properties and change distributionUrl

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete the .gradle file in your C:\Users\Axl you will find the .gradle file and Delete it!
2. Go to your VsCode/IDE :> run flutter clean
3. then > flutter pub get (this will download the new gradle which is Mensoined in your Gradle wrapper  eg distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip
4. flutter run -v [will Start your gradle demon running & your project also will start to RUN]
5. Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

change distributionUrl in gradle-wrapper.properties

Answer (score 0):

```
defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.ducafecat.woo_commerce.flutter_woo_commerce_getx_learn"
    // You can update the following values to match your application needs. 
    // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
    // minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
    minSdkVersion 21
    // targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion 33 //31->33
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by referring Gradle capability matrix. It shows that, what java version is required to running specific version of Gradle. You just need to match the java SDK version and Gradle version accordingly.

[Gradle Compatibility Matrix](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html)

[image: SDK version]

[image: Gradle version]

Answer (score 0):

On linux, you can run the following command to find out the file causing the issue

```
strace -f -t -e trace=file flutter run
```

This will give a lot of output. When gradle finishes with error, look at the output right before the failure and you will find the problematic file, in my case it was:

```
[pid 13509] 12:00:48 stat("~/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-7.5-all/6qsw290k5lz422uaf8jf6m7co/gradle-7.5-all.zip", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=44071076, ...}) = 0
```

Remove the file and try again, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the .gradle folder under C/USER/[PC NAME]/.gradle worked for me. My API level is 33 and is working with latest android studio version.