# Gradle sync failed with zip END header not found

Tags: intellij-idea, build.gradle

Why does IntelliJ fail to sync a new gradle dependency?

For a newly unzipped project opened in IntelliJ, the build failed and it shows:

> zip END header not found

Comment: Seems that .jar in Gradle local repository is corrupted. Try to remove and re-download. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52411697/intellij-compilation-error-zip-end-header-not-found

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1 zip END header not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67901965/flutter-gradle-task-assembledebug-failed-with-exit-code-1-zip-end-header-not-fou)

Answer (score 0):

It looks a duplicated question.

---

Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68375780/11741935 for details.

Comment: It would better to flag the question as a duplicate, rather than copying the answer from the duplication question.