# I got this error when I tried to run my flutter code

Tags: flutter

I am get this error when I try to run my code in vscode. Help please!

```
Using hardware rendering with device Android SDK built for x86. If you notice graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with "--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.zerror(ZipFile.java:1581)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.findEND(ZipFile.java:1476)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.initCEN(ZipFile.java:1483)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.<init>(ZipFile.java:1288)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1251)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:732)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.get(ZipFile.java:849)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:247)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:177)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:191)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:214)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:74)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                           1,045ms
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I tried to solve the gradle issues but they too don't seem to work

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/76496

Comment: @CodeCaster this didn't worked for me. I deleted the gradle file but still it is not done

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67901965/flutter-gradle-task-assembledebug-failed-with-exit-code-1-zip-end-header-not-fou

Answer (score 0):

first of all if you are living in banned country you need to use VPN application and preferred country is US (I suggest to use Proton VPN you can use free services of it)
and then try to rebuild your code
if you still have the same issue you need to delete Gradle folder in your system and redownload it
I have faced this issue before and for me I copied the files in new project and that's worked for me maybe that help you