# Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found

Tags: java, android, gradle

Able to create release build but when I add dexguard and try to create a release build its throws the following error

```
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerNotificationException: Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:89)
at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:346)
at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:249)
at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:141)
at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:37)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy44.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$NotifyAfterEvaluate$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:247)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$NotifyAfterEvaluate$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:244)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.stepEvaluationListener(DefaultProject.java:1433)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$NotifyAfterEvaluate.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:253)
... 182 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at com.bugsnag.android.gradle.GroovyCompat.getDexguardVersionString(GroovyCompat.groovy:55)
    at com.bugsnag.android.gradle.internal.DexguardCompatKt.getDexguardMajorVersionInt(DexguardCompat.kt:81)
    at com.bugsnag.android.gradle.MappingFileProviderKt.findMappingFiles(MappingFileProvider.kt:33)
    at com.bugsnag.android.gradle.MappingFileProviderKt.createMappingFileProvider(MappingFileProvider.kt:22)
    at com.bugsnag.android.gradle.BugsnagPlugin$registerBugsnagTasksForVariant$1.execute(BugsnagPlugin.kt:216)
    at com.bugsnag.android.gradle.BugsnagPlugin$registerBugsnagTasksForVariant$1.execute(BugsnagPlugin.kt:68)
    at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext$CurrentApplication$1.execute(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:123)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction$1.run(DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator.java:110)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction.execute(DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator.java:107)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultMutationGuard$2.execute(DefaultMutationGuard.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultMutationGuard$2.execute(DefaultMutationGuard.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.configureEach(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:185)
    at com.bugsnag.android.gradle.BugsnagPlugin.registerBugsnagTasksForVariant(BugsnagPlugin.kt:206)
    at com.bugsnag.android.gradle.BugsnagPlugin.access$registerBugsnagTasksForVariant(BugsnagPlugin.kt:68)
    at com.bugsnag.android.gradle.BugsnagPlugin$setupBugsnagPlugin$1$1.execute(BugsnagPlugin.kt:158)
    at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext$CurrentApplication$1.execute(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:123)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction$1.run(DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator.java:110)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction.execute(DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator.java:107)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultMutationGuard$2.execute(DefaultMutationGuard.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.configureEach(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:185)
    at com.bugsnag.android.gradle.BugsnagPlugin$setupBugsnagPlugin$1.execute(BugsnagPlugin.kt:152)
    at com.bugsnag.android.gradle.BugsnagPlugin$setupBugsnagPlugin$1.execute(BugsnagPlugin.kt:68)
    at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext$CurrentApplication$1.execute(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:123)
    at
```

my config

- Gradle 7.4.2
- Kotlin:       1.5.31
- Groovy:       3.0.9
- Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
- JVM:          11.0.8 (OpenLogic 11.0.8+0-adhoc.centos.jdk11u)
- OS:           Linux 4.9.32-15.41.amzn1.x86_64 amd64

I cant point the java version to 1.8 as a project is targeting android 12

Comment: `zip END header not found` could be caused by a ZIP/APK file that has not been written completely. Or it is a bug in the BugsnagPlugin as the error is caused by this plugin (see stack trace).

Comment: i removed BugsnagPlugin still same error

Comment: This helped me in one shot and i tried on Windows https://stackoverflow.com/a/69718476/16278422

Answer (score 0):

**Android Studio**

This error indicates that there is a problem with your ZIP file. It could be corrupted, incomplete, or incompatible with your version of Android Studio. Here are some alternatives:

1- **Change the Gradle version**. You can find available versions here: https://services.gradle.org/distributions/. Make sure it is the bin version, for example: https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.1-bin.zip. Then make sure to change the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file accordingly.

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0-bin.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
```

2- As you changed the Gradle **must change** it in `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$agp_version"
```

3- **Delete** the .gradle folder in your project directory and reimport the project. This will force Android Studio to download a fresh copy of Gradle.

```
C:\Users\moriz\.gradle\wrapper\dists
C:\Users\moriz\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-8.0-bin\ca5e32bp14vu59qr306oxotwh
```

4- Check your project for **any ZIP files** that could be causing the issue. For example, if you use Bugsnag, you may need to update Dexguard or temporarily disable it.