# Cause: zip END header not found. Problem not solving by any methods in stackoverflow

Tags: android, compiler-errors, synchronization, build.gradle

I have checked all the code, deleted the .gradle folder, deleted cache folder, invalidated caches and restarted, but problem not solved.

Please help me with it.[build view of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLG8A.jpg)

1. checked the code and typo error
2. invalidated cache and restart
3. deleted cache folder
4. checked log file for errors
5. deleted .gradle folder
6. tried every option that was given in stackoverflow

Comment: Its possible one/some of the zip somewhere might be corrupted. Try using answers on this que.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13565082/how-can-i-force-gradle-to-redownload-dependencies

Comment: Try this method,  https://stackoverflow.com/a/76801488/12272687

Answer (score 1):

This error means that there is something wrong with your ZIP file. It could be corrupted, incomplete or incompatible with your Android Studio version. Here are some possible solutions:

1- Change the Gradle version. You can find available versions here: https://services.gradle.org/distributions/. Make sure it is the bin version, for example: https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.1-bin.zip. Then make sure to change the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file accordingly.

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0-bin.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
```

2- Delete the .gradle folder in your project directory and reimport the project. This will force Android Studio to download a fresh copy of Gradle.

```
C:\Users\moriz\.gradle\wrapper\dists
C:\Users\moriz\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-8.0-bin\ca5e32bp14vu59qr306oxotwh
```

3- Check if you have any ZIP files in your project that could be causing the problem. For example, if you are using Bugsnag, you might need to update the Dexguard version or disable it temporarily.

Comment: Deleting .gradle. Its working

Answer (score 0):

just delete the whole grandle folder found in users (if not found use search everything software and type gradle you will view  it in the user directory but not in a given project ) in users then restart your Pc open android studio it will automatically start gradle sync and build will start but make sure you have a stable network some networks have limitations .

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution for you: temporarily deactivate the Space plugin (File -> Settings... -> Plugins) and try. At least that error message stopped appearing for me and I can work.