Error : Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
I'm trying to run flutter on Linux mint using vs code but this error appears ,it happens only when i try to run the code on an emulator or my phone

i've tried to use intellij instead but it didn't work and i got the same error, i tried to reinstall flutter and run some commands also .

Please check this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67901965/flutter-gradle-task-assembledebug-failed-with-exit-code-1-zip-end-header-not-fou
